# What is the difference between ObjectNode and JsonNode in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

According to the documetation of [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html):

> Most mutators, however, need to be accessed through specific sub-classes (such as [`ObjectNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html)  and ArrayNode).

However I am still confused since some stackoverflow answers seem to use them quite interchangeably. What different purpose do they serve?

Comment: JsonNode is a base class that ObjectNode and ArrayNode extend. E.g. you cannot get an item at a specific index in a JsonNode or ObjectNode but you can in an ArrayNode.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`JsonNode` is a base class that `ObjectNode` and `ArrayNode` extend. `JsonNode` represents any valid Json structure whereas `ObjectNode` and `ArrayNode` are particular implementations for objects (aka maps) and arrays, respectively.

`ArrayNode` has specific methods for dealing with arrays such as `get(index i)` E.g. you cannot get an item at a specific index in a `JsonNode` or `ObjectNode` but you can in an `ArrayNode`.

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver I am not sure your edit is a good fit for this answer. It turns a straightforward concise answer into a longer discursive narrative about a possible source of confusion. I do not feel sure that confusion is widespread. I personally have not felt it. Would you be willing put your thoughts on the possible source of confusion into their own answer for this question?

Comment: Yeah absolutely :)

Answer (score 1):

To address OP's point about Stack Overflow answers using `ObjectNode` and `JsonNode` interchangeably: a possible source of the confusion you see is that `JsonNode` [implements most of the functionality of both `ObjectNode` and `ArrayNode`](https://github.com/codehaus/jackson/blob/master/src/java/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.java), returning mostly `false` or `null` by default. The sub-types then override their respective methods to work correctly (e.g. indexing for `ArrayNode`, named access for `ObjectNode`). The Javadoc says:

> As a general design rule, most accessors ("getters") are included in this [JsonNode] base class, to allow for traversing structure without type casts. Most mutators, however, need to be accessed through specific sub-classes (such as [ObjectNode] and [ArrayNode]). This seems sensible because proper type information is generally available when building or modifying trees, but less often when reading a tree (newly built from parsed JSON content)

*"[T]o allow for traversing structure without type casts"* is key, and is the reason that you can often get away with using `JsonNode` all the time, because as long as the methods you're calling match the sub-type of the object data actually got parsed into, they work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`JsonNode` and `ObjectNode` are both classes in the Jackson library used for working with JSON data in Java.

`JsonNode` is an abstract class that represents a node in a JSON tree. It can be used to read and navigate through JSON data, but it doesn't allow modifications to the underlying data. Because it's abstract, you can't create a `JsonNode` object directly. Instead, you can use one of its concrete subclasses, such as `ObjectNode`, `ArrayNode`, or `ValueNode`.

`ObjectNode` is a subclass of `JsonNode` that specifically represents a JSON object. It allows you to modify the underlying JSON data by adding, removing, or changing properties. An `ObjectNode` is created with the `JsonNodeFactory` class, which provides methods for creating different types of `JsonNode` objects.

In general, you should use `JsonNode` when you only need to read JSON data, and don't need to modify it. You might use `ObjectNode` when you need to modify the data, such as when you're building up a JSON object programmatically.